# AdMob not loading ads in ionic/angular app

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, admob, ionic-framework

I'm having some problems getting ads to work. I can't rap my brain around why it isn't working. I have the following plugins installed:

com.google.playservices 19.0.0 "Google Play Services for Android"
com.rjfun.cordova.plugin.admob 2.1.7 "AdMob"
I've have used this tutorial: https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/06/using-admob-ionicframework/

This is my code in the apps.js:

```js
 .run(function ($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }

        // select the right Ad Id according to platform
        if (window.plugins && window.plugins.AdMob) {
            var admob_key = "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx";
            var admob = window.plugins.AdMob;
            admob.createBannerView(
                {
                    'publisherId': admob_key,
                    'adSize': admob.AD_SIZE.BANNER,
                    'bannerAtTop': false
                },
                function () {
                    admob.requestAd(
                        {'isTesting': false},
                        function () {
                            admob.showAd(true);
                        },
                        function () {
                            console.log('failed to request ad');
                        }
                    );
                },
                function () {
                    console.log('failed to create banner view');
                }
            );
        }
    });
});
```

This results in a black banner area at the bottom of the app, however no ad is ever loaded. This code is currently live, on the admob site I can see a couple hundred session. However my impressions and Request rpm are both at zero for a couple of days now. Anybody have any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: You can find another tutorial for com.admob.google plugin here: https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova/wiki/Angular.js,-Ionic-apps

Comment: @Ron: did you manage to solve this in the end?

Comment: did you solve it. I am having the same issue. In my case, I dont see a banner at all.

Answer (score 8):

I also spent 2 days to make it work, After reading lot of docs i got it working finally. Below code worked for me. I have written detailed blog post also and working code download as well as working apk. [Read Here](http://www.amitpatil.me/google-admob-ads-with-ionic-android-app/) OR follow below steps (I assume you already have publisher id and all other things)

1) Install admob plugin

```
ionic plugin add cordova-admob
```

2) Include `angular-admob.js` file

```
 <script src="lib/angular-admob/angular-admob.js"></script>
```

3) Call body onload function to init admob

```
 <body ng-app="starter" onload="runads()">
```

4) Put below code at the bottom of page (Dont forget to replace your publisher id with 'ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/IIIIIIIIII'). It works only on mobile devices and not in pc browser. Once app started wait for a 20-25 seconds to load ads.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function runads(){
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
  }

  function initAds() {
    if (admob) {
      var adPublisherIds = {
        ios : {
          banner : "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/IIIIIIIIII"
        },
        android : {
          banner : "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/IIIIIIIIII",
          interstitial : "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/IIIIIIIIII"
        }
      };

      var admobid = (/(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ? adPublisherIds.android : adPublisherIds.ios;

      admob.setOptions({
        publisherId:      admobid.banner,
        interstitialAdId: admobid.interstitial,
        tappxIdiOs:       "/XXXXXXXXX/Pub-XXXX-iOS-IIII",
        tappxIdAndroid:   "/XXXXXXXXX/Pub-XXXX-Android-AAAA",
        tappxShare:       0.5
      });

      registerAdEvents();

    } else {
      alert('AdMobAds plugin not ready');
    }
  }

  function onAdLoaded(e) {
    if (e.adType === admob.AD_TYPE.INTERSTITIAL) {
      admob.showInterstitialAd();
      showNextInterstitial = setTimeout(function() {
        admob.requestInterstitialAd();
      }, 2 * 60 * 1000); // 2 minutes
    }
  }

  // optional, in case respond to events
  function registerAdEvents() {
    document.addEventListener(admob.events.onAdLoaded, onAdLoaded);
    document.addEventListener(admob.events.onAdFailedToLoad, function (e) {});
    document.addEventListener(admob.events.onAdOpened, function (e) {});
    document.addEventListener(admob.events.onAdClosed, function (e) {});
    document.addEventListener(admob.events.onAdLeftApplication, function (e) {});
    document.addEventListener(admob.events.onInAppPurchaseRequested, function (e) {});
  }

  function onDeviceReady() {
    document.removeEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
    initAds();

    // display a banner at startup
    admob.createBannerView();

    // request an interstitial
    admob.requestInterstitialAd();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked for me also. But my app size is increased by 3MB after installing cordova-admob plugin. Is there any way to decrease it.

Answer (score 1):

Raymond is right, I have used the following code to install the plugin

```
> Ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-admobpro
```

> *Note: Please upgrade your cordova CLI to version 5*

Open **app.js** and just paste the following code inside **.run** method and done!

```
var admobid = {};

// select the right Ad Id according to platform

if( /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) { 
    admobid = { // for Android
        banner: 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111',
        interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/NNNNNNNNNN'
    };
} else if(/(ipod|iphone|ipad)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    admobid = { // for iOS
        banner: 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111',
        interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/NNNNNNNNNN'
    };
} else {
    admobid = { // for Windows Phone
        banner: 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111',
        interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/NNNNNNNNNN'
    };
}

if(window.AdMob) AdMob.createBanner( {
  adId:admobid.banner, 
  isTesting: true,
  position:AdMob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER, 
  autoShow:true} );

if(window.AdMob) AdMob.prepareInterstitial( {
  adId:admobid.interstitial, 
  autoShow:true} );
```

> Don't forget to set 'isTesting: false' while deploying your app to the
>   store.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In fact the version of AdMob plugin in the blog post isn't supported anymore, you have to use the new one cordova-admob-pro which works fine with all android versions and iOS versions as well.

Here a blog post about how to use the new version:

http://redwanhilali.com/ionic-admob-integration/

I hope it helps.

Comment: Where is the blog post?

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of the plugin you are using. Please migrate to the pro version:

```
cordova plugin add com.google.cordova.admob
```

Or (if you are using cordova CLI v5.x),

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-admobpro
```

Here is a working demo using cordova-plugin-admobpro in a Ionic framework APP:
https://github.com/floatinghotpot/admob-demo-app-ionic

Suggest:

1. Follow the commands in the link to build a working demo;
2. Look into the content in demo/ folder and check file js/admob.js

https://github.com/floatinghotpot/admob-demo-app-ionic/blob/master/demo/js/admob.js

You can even directly copy this file to your project, then reference in your index.html:

```
<script src="js/admob.js"></script>
```

Like this demo index.html:
https://github.com/floatinghotpot/admob-demo-app-ionic/blob/master/demo/index.html#L21