# Ionic Admob Not Displaying

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using the following code to add admob on my ionic app, but it is not showing. I added the code in  $ionicPlatform.ready. And I have added the cordova plugin.

```js
if(window.plugins && window.plugins.AdMob) {
                var admob_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
                var admob = window.plugins.AdMob;
                admob.createBannerView(
                    {
                        'publisherId': admob_key,
                        'adSize': admob.AD_SIZE.BANNER,
                        'bannerAtTop': false
                    },
                    function() {
                        admob.requestAd(
                            { 'isTesting': false },
                            function() {
                                admob.showAd(true);
                            },
                            function() { console.log('failed to request ad'); }
                        );
                    },
                    function() { console.log('failed to create banner view'); }
                );
            }
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You can try this one https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/06/using-admob-ionicframework/

Comment: That's how I did it http://stackoverflow.com/a/34556704/1276616

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add admob plugin and add  script **"admob.js"** from admob plugin folder.

its my Ionic v1 code

its work for me

**cordova plugin add admob@5.5.0**

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {      
     admob.initAdmob("admob banner ID", "admob interstitial ID");
    admob.showBanner(admob.BannerSize.BANNER, admob.Position.BOTTOM_APP);
    var admobParam = new admob.Params();
    admobParam.isTesting = true;
    admob.showBanner(admob.BannerSize.BANNER, admob.Position.BOTTOM_APP, admobParam);
  });
})
```