# How to implement Admob into Ionic?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, admob, cordova-admob

I followed the instructions of this post:
[AdMob not loading ads in ionic/angular app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28292927/admob-not-loading-ads-in-ionic-angular-app/34556704#34556704)

When I run the app via "ionic build ios && ionic emulate ios" I get no ads, no black bar nothing.

What did I miss?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the instructions at https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova/wiki/Angular.js,-Ionic-apps:

- Install the plugin as usual (see here):

  ```
  ionic plugin add cordova-admob
  ```
- Include the following script in your `index.html` (just it, no need to copy any file: the plugin is in charge to copy the script when the app is prepared):

  ```
  <script src="lib/angular-admob/angular-admob.js"></script>
  ```
- Call AdMob from your Ionic app.

Here is a quick example:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['admobModule']);

app.config(['admobSvcProvider', function (admobSvcProvider) {
  // Optionally you can configure the options here:
  admobSvcProvider.setOptions({
    publisherId:          "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/BBBBBBBBBB",  // Required
    interstitialAdId:     "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/IIIIIIIIII",  // Optional
  });
}]);


app.run(['admobSvc', function (admobSvc) {
  // Also you could configure the options here (or in any controller):
  // admobSvcProvider.setOptions({ ... });

  admobSvc.createBannerView();
  // You could also call admobSvc.createBannerView(options);


  // Handle events:
  $rootScope.$on(admobSvc.events.onAdOpened, function onAdOpened(evt, e) {
    console.log('adOpened: type of ad:' + e.adType);
  });
}]);
```

Comment: No more working, getting inAppPurchase error while making android build.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. `ionic platform add android
    ionic platform add ios`
2. `cordova plugin add com.rjfun.cordova.plugin.admob`
3. Paste these code in run module of app.js's

code:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.plugins && window.plugins.AdMob) {
        var admob_key = device.platform == "Android" ? "ANDROID_PUBLISHER_KEY" : "IOS_PUBLISHER_KEY";
        var admob = window.plugins.AdMob;
        admob.createBannerView( {
            'publisherId': admob_key,
            'adSize': admob.AD_SIZE.BANNER,
            'bannerAtTop': false
        }, 
        function() {
            admob.requestAd({ 'isTesting': false }, 
        function() {
            admob.showAd(true);
        }, 
        function() { console.log('failed to request ad'); });
        }, 
        function() { console.log('failed to create banner view'); });
    }
});
```

Regards.

Comment: If you want to use more powerful and new features, please use the pro version instead. The totoally re-designed [AdMob PluginPro](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro) is proved much better and more than welcome by Cordova APP/game developers.

Comment: Getting this error:
Error: Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/com.rjfun.cordova.plugin.admob

Comment: May be repository has been moved. You can try https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro as @Jon suggested.