# Native Admob ads using ionic/cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, firebase, admob, cordova-admob

I have actually successfully implemented banner and interstitial ads in my app but I would love to have a less intrusive way of making a few extra bucks to keep the lights one.

I'd really like to implement Native ads through admob in my cordova/ionic project. The problem is I can't use the SDK and I can't reverse engineer adsense to show in the app because that is against policy.

I've been searching Stack for answers but the only think I really see is implementation help for banners and interstitials (which I'm good with). My question is, Has anyone had any luck with implementing native ads using admob in a cordova/ionic project? Link below to "native ads" so we are all on the same page. Basically it means in the main feed and not floating at the bottom or poping up to take full screen.

[AdMob Native Ads](https://www.google.com/admob/monetize.html#?monetize-tabset_activeEl=native-ads)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

They don't support currently. Here is answer from Google Employee..[Answer in Google official forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/iwd_lyJcOkA)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this tutorial in https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova/wiki/Angular.js,-Ionic-apps

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/38019618/513570

Comment: both of those are for banner and interstitials. I am looking to do native ads.

Comment: You are right. From what I know, ionic & cordova uses a **unique layout view** that has a webview inside and it's fullscreen. The concept of native ads is that you insert a **native ads view** between your app views. Having that your ionic app has just one view, it would mean that the cordova/ionic webview should be splitted into different views and for the moment cordova is not designed for this. I see no option for the moment to use native ads. Will think on it anyway.

Comment: I actually found a solution. Amazon offers a native HTML web-view solution that I can slip in-between the content on my app pretty seamlessly.

Comment: @BrennanAltringer would you be able to provide more information on that Amazon Web-View solution. Is that specific to developing for Fire OS devices? I've been looking for a way to have inline Admob adverts in Phonegap/Cordova for a while now!

Comment: Yeah it looks like Amazon sucks too... but one last thing we found was using Flurry with is a Yahoo product. That platform has a Cordova plugin that we have been messing with. I think that would be our best bet. Check that out and let me know what you find. Otherwise we are going to scrap ads or just use interstitials or something. @robobobobo

Comment: I recently came across the same problem. My solution was facebook's mobile native ads (still in beta), you can take a look. (Easy to implement)

Comment: @MasterJohn Can you tell how to implement facebook's mobile native ads. Any tutorial help link?

Answer (score 0):

So far it's not possible to implement AdMob native ad in Ionic.
But we've Facebook Audience Network, and we can implement its native ad easily [FAN native ad: Ionic 2](http://technotip.com/5128/facebook-native-ads-ionic-2/)