# using Admob native ads in ionic project

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-admob, phonegap-admob

I'm working on ionic project. I have integrate Admob by using this plugin cordova-plugin-admobpro, it work perfectly this is the code that i use :

```
    //======admob code start=============

  var admobid = {};
    // select the right Ad Id according to platform
    if( /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) { 
        admobid = { // for Android
            banner: 'ca-app-pub-84538xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-845xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        };
    } else if(/(ipod|iphone|ipad)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        admobid = { // for iOS
            banner: 'ca-app-pub-845xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-84xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        };
    } else {
        admobid = { // for Windows Phone
            banner: 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        };
    }


  if(window.AdMob) AdMob.createBanner( {
      adId:admobid.banner, 
      position:AdMob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER, 
      autoShow:true} );


//=======AdMob Code End=======
```

Now what i neeed is to add more add inside the view in my content ( ADMOB NATIVE i think ) any idea?
Can I use ADsense Ads ?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/38071505/513570

Comment: [Find here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37954305/how-to-implement-admob-into-ionic/38019618#38019618) answer from stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

In ionic with google admob we can't create 'Native ads'

we can use 'Facebook audience network' ads for integrating the native ads in ionic.

we have a clear cordova plugin to integrate facebook ads which make my work simpler.

you can refer this cordova plugin : https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-facebookads